# Libgdx load image files using loadTexture or AssetManager fileNotFound exception

Tags: android, libgdx, load, filenotfoundexception, android-assets

I am building an Android game using libgdx, I have a set of image files in /res directory, for example in /res/drawable-nodpi/image.png. However, I cannot use loadTexture or use AssetManager to load the image file except if the file is put under /assets.

Is there any workaround? I do not want to copy all the files into /assets. They are put in /res for a reason. I don't know why it is just so un-flexible.

Comment: while loading give the path of res folder. Also make a res folder in dekstop project also to make consistency. never tried but i guess this should do it